# IIS Express Access denied

Tags: c#, iis-express

I am trying to create new file in visual studio 2012

```
fileStream = new FileStream("google_com.txt", FileMode.CreateNew);
```

But i keep getting this error
Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\google_com.txt' is denied.

Plz help to fix this poblem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Solutions:**

1. Put a specific location for `google_com.txt` file. like `C:\google_com.txt`. Actually it is not allowing to create the file in default location(inside program files) as it might not have the proper privilege.
2. If you want to create the file in default location(inside program files) run Visual Studio as Administrator.(R-Click-> Run as Administrator).

Answer (score 7):

Run Visual Studio as **Administrator**

Answer (score 3):

You can't write to the Program Files folders on Windows Vista or later unless you're running elevated/as an administrator.

You should be writing to the application's App_Data folder if you need to write anywhere. Look into using Server.MapPath().

Answer (score 2):

If this is in a web app, the file will be created in the application's root, which in this case is your iis express directory. Run Visual Studio as Administrator, or change the location of the file by specifying an explicit path.

Answer (score 0):

Official Microsoft response:

> Issue occurs because of missing permissions on a local resource that
>   the ASP.NET application tries to access If you are unable to get a
>   clear description of the problem because of a custom error message,
>   run FileMon and reproduce the problem. Stop and save the capture as
>   FileMon.xls and open the file in Microsoft Excel. On the Data menu,
>   click Filter, and then click AutoFilter to use the filtering
>   capabilities of Excel. Now select the drop-down list in column F and
>   look for "ACCESS DENIED" errors.
>
> A sample FileMon output is shown below. 10381 1:01:11 PM w3wp.exe:2320
>   OPEN C:\winnt\microsoft.net\framework\v1.1.4322\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\sessiontest\8832e585\275ec327\global.asax.xml ACCESS DENIED NT
>   AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE  As you can see from the filtered results,
>   we have narrowed down the cause of the problem. FileMon shows that the
>   NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE account is missing NTFS permissions on
>   the C:\Winnt\Microsoft.net\Framework\v1.1.4322\Temporary ASP.NET Files
>   folder. This should be straight forward to fix.  For more information
>   about using FileMon to troubleshoot ASP.NET, click the following
>   article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base

https://support.microsoft.com/es-ve/help/910449/troubleshooting-common-permissions-and-security-related-issues-in-asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Server.MapPath("~/ FolderName / google_com.txt ")
```