# Saving item in textbox as textfile

Tags: c#, asp.net

how can i save my item on textbox3 as text file without default location
this is my code on button as of now i can save the file in textfile but it has default location

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      TextWriter txt = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\casti\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Text\\Text.txt");
      txt.Write(TextBox3.Text);
      txt.Close();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of streamwriter you can use filestream to achieve this.
Try something like this.

```
       var filePath = "your destination path";

        FileStream fstream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);  
        StreamWriter streamWriter= new StreamWriter(fstream);  
        streamWriter.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);  
        streamWriter.Write(TextBox3.Text);  
        streamWriter.Flush();  
        streamWriter.Close();
```

Comment: sir i get this eror
Error CS0103 The name 'm_WriterParameter' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\your destination path' is denied.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to change the stream writer name. Please check now

Comment: to solve the access path issue check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23020934/iis-express-access-denied